# Is that true, that building projects in tfs build 2012 is not possible with overriding OutputPath

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I try to update TFS from 2010 to 2012 and have Problems in TFS Build.

In 2010 i use this Solution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/04/13/customizableoutdir-in-tfs-2010.aspx

But after updating, all projects are in the same (solutions)-folder. I have seen that, there is a new way to seperate projects:

http://blog.codeassassin.com/2012/05/10/override-the-tfs-team-build-outdir-property-net-4-5/

Can anybody tell something about that, or have same problems?

Answer (score 1):

I have spent almost whole day playing with OutDir properties in build process template and *.csproj files with no luck.

The problem I was trying to resolve: I had a solution with multiple Console/Windows applications projects. I needed to have a separate folder for each application instead of one single heap of all DLLs and EXEs in one folder to make it easy to pack *.zip archives of compiled applications.

Finally I found blog post you mentioned - http://blog.codeassassin.com/2012/05/10/override-the-tfs-team-build-outdir-property-net-4-5/

For me it is working like a charm - now I have a separate folder for each project and I don't need to worry about what files do I need to include in resulting *.zip archive.